# Tainted string message from Coverity using getenv

Tags: c, coverity, coverity-prevent

Running Coverity on my code results in tainted string error message. I am using the "path" variable declared in the stack, so I am not sure why I am seeing errors. I can only think that using `getenv()` directly in the `strncpy()` is causing the error. Would the fix below eliminate this error?

```
char path[1024] = {NULL, };
if(getenv("A"))
    strncpy(path, getenv("A"), strlen(getenv("A")));
```

to

```
char path[1024] = {NULL, };
char * adriver = getenv("A");
if(adriver)
    strncpy(path, adriver, strlen(adriver));
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use NULL as an initializer for a `char`, especially if the implementation defines `NULL` as `((void *)0)`, which is a legitimate value in C (but not legitimate in C++).  You could use `char path[1024] = "";` instead.  You are also abusing `strncpy()`; you should be limiting it to the length of `path` (minus 1).  If someone runs your code with a PATH that is more than 1023 characters long, you will overflow the array and may end up crashing and will not get a null-terminated string.  It is unlikely that either of these is a factor in the 'tainted string' message.

Comment: Having looked at the code again, I realize you're doing a superfluous `memset()` after initializing `path` to all bytes zero.

Comment: to add to @JonathanLeffler sir's comment, the second approach is better, because it saves you two redundant `getenv()` calls.

Comment: At one time, [JS1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4192931/js1) observed — accurately — that: _In the second piece of code, you should realize that `if (!adriver)` is only true if `adriver` is `NULL`. In other words, you have reversed the meaning of the `if` statement from the first piece of code. You probably meant `if (adriver)`._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I made the changes. But I am still not sure if this eliminates tainted string issue.

Comment: @JayChung: I am not surprised that the changes I suggested didn't resolve the tainted strings problem.  I don't know anything specific about Coverity and tainted strings.  By analogy with Perl (a dangerous game to play), I'm assuming that you have to do some analysis of the value returned by `getenv()` before you do much with it in order to get rid of the taintedness.  But I've not gone manual bashing to find out more -- you can do that about as well as I can.

Comment: You might find [Tainted string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703826/tainted-string-in-c) of some help.  A Google search on terms 'coverity tainted string' shows a number of other related items.  I haven't found a definitive answer, but neither have I visited the Coverity site to see what manuals are available.

Answer (score 9):

No, this will probably not fix the error.

Coverity is telling you that the data within environment variable "A" could be pretty much anything; this data is not under the control of your program.

Therefore, you need to have some sanity checks on the data before you use it.

Your proposed fix will currently have a buffer overflow, if somebody sets environment variable A to a string containing 1025 characters.

Additionally, neither version of code will ever NUL-terminate the "path" string. This is because, you are using strncpy, which will not NUL-terminate if the byte limit is applied (which it will in this case, because you say "limit the copied string to the length I just got from the string").

What you should be doing, is size-check the string first. If it is too large, return some sort of error code; the path in variable A is too big, so your code will not function as desired. If it is not too large, copy it into the path buffer. If you want to use strncpy, make sure to leave room for a NUL at the end, and then explicitly add it, since strncpy is not guaranteed to put a NUL there.

Comment: You are 100% right on why Coverity complained.  But, there is no reason to use `strncpy` here.  In fact, it is only useful for a little tiny corner case.  You have already computed the length to know if it is going to fit.  It's probably much more efficient to just use `memcpy` to copy it, then manually add the NUL at the end.

Comment: The main reason `strncpy()` is probably not useful is that if the contents of the environment variable are legitimate but too long, then truncating the value is the wrong thing to do.  Such truncation could be a security issue in itself, but in any case is unlikely to produce the desired beharior.  The program should terminate with an error instead, or at least reject the overlength value altogether.

Comment: The end of a string is 0, not NULL.

Comment: You're right...to be pedantic a zero is an ASCII "NUL", not " NULL". Corrected. ;-)

Comment: To be ultra-pedantic, a C string is terminated with a 0 byte, which is not an ASCII "NUL" character. On some processors (namely DSPs), bytes are 32 bits. ASCII is not.

Answer (score 8):

Your code is incorrect: you have a potential buffer overflow in both alternatives.

I am not sure **Coverity** diagnoses the problem correctly, you did not post the exact error message. Coverity is possibly indicating that you use a string from the environment, that could have any length, potentially causing a buffer overflow when copied by your code into a 1024 byte buffer, indeed it is a good thing it pointed you to this.  Here is why:

`strncpy` does not do what you think it does.  This function should **never** be used, its semantics are error prone, it is not the right tool for your purpose. `strncpy(dest, src, n)` copies no more than `n` chars from `src` to `dest` and fills the rest of the array at `dest` with `'\0'` bytes until `n` bytes have been written. `dest` must point to an array of at least `n` chars. If `src` is shorter, the behavior is inefficient as the padding is usually unnecessary, but if `src` has a length of at least `n`, `dest` will not be null terminated by `strncpy`, leading to undefined behavior in many cases.

Your code:

```
char path[1024] = { NULL, };
if (getenv("A"))
    strncpy(path, getenv("A"), strlen(getenv("A")));
```

is equivalent to

```
char path[1024] = { NULL, };
if (getenv("A"))
    memcpy(path, getenv("A"), strlen(getenv("A")));
```

As you see, no real protection is granted.

You call `getenv` 3 times, it would indeed be more efficient to use your alternative implementation, but there are other problems:

You initialize `path` with `{ NULL, }`.  This is inconsistent and in many cases incorrect.  `NULL` is commonly #defined as `((void*)0)`, thus an invalid initializer for `char`.  `path` could be initialized this way:

```
char path[1024] = { 0 };
```

To avoid overflowing the destination buffer, use this code:

```
char path[1024] = { 0 };
char *p = getenv("A");
if (p != NULL) {
    strncat(path, p, sizeof(path) - 1);
}
```

But this would truncate the environment value, which may not be appropriate depending on how you use `path`.

An alternative is to use the environment value directly:

```
char *path = getenv("A");
if (path == NULL)
    path = "";
```

And if you change the environment values with `setenv` during the execution of your program, you might want to make a copy of the environment value with `path = strdup(path);`.  This might also fix the *tainted string* warning from Coverity, although the copy would be the same size as the original and enough memory might not be available, which should be tested.  Judging from [Tainted string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703826/tainted-string-in-c) , it seems Coverity is a bit extreme about tainted strings.  While the warning you get indicates a real problem, getting rid of the warning may sometimes require strange workarounds.

Comment: so far only 2 things got rid of the coverity warning for me: [1] in C use `strdup` followed by a call to a macro that did an `snprintf` [2] in C++ `<<` to a `stringstream` and then return `.str()`. Not sure why `strdup` by itself didn't work in the C++ file.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the fix below eliminate this error?

No, but this almost certainly would:

```
char *e = getenv("A");
char path[e ? strlen(e) + 1 : 1];
strcpy(path, e ? e : "");
```

The main problem with your code occurs when `getenv("A")` returns a string that's 1024 bytes or longer; copying this into `path` as you are results in a buffer overflow, as it isn't guaranteed that `strlen(getenv("A"))` will be less than or equal to 1024. You could fix this by using:

```
strncpy(path, getenv("A"), sizeof path); // NOT RECOMMENDED
```

... but then `path` won't be terminated with a `'\0'` character; `path` won't be a string in this situation, because by definition a string *must* be terminated with a `'\0'` character... This means you wouldn't be able to use it as a string.

That is what Coverity is most likely complaining about here, and my code eliminates the problem by using a VLA (variable length array) that's large enough to store the entire string, plus the `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *path = getenv("A");
```

isn't that all you need? Is there a reason you need to make a copy of what getenv returns? If so,

```
char *path = NULL, *A = getenv("A");

if(A != NULL)
   {
   path = malloc(strlen(A)+1);
   strcpy(path, A);
   }
```

Comment: Use strdup for copying a string and allocating memory at the same time.

Comment: Simple solution, but with a semantic difference: `path` is `NULL` as opposed to `""` if the environment does not have a value for `A`.

Comment: strdup... us old folks didn't have such niceties... Had to walk uphill both ways just to go to school 'n' all... you young folks got it good... Where's my spitoon??? :-P